# How to delete or remove duplicate entires from mysql 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to clear my database on special user events. 
I have to clear the DB entires in the table if PID and UID entires are the same. 
My server is having mysql 5.x, so the CET / Over() analytics functions are not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Table 

ID  PID  UID
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    1    1
4    1    1
5    3    2
6    2    5
```

Desired table after cleanup

```
ID  PID  UID
1    1    1
5    3    2
6    2    5
```

Comment: Please show the results *after* the operation.

Comment: Do you only want to remove the duplicates, or remove all rows that contain duplicates?

Comment: Do you want to delete 1,2,3,4 ??

Comment: updated the summary with desired table after operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self join:

```
delete t 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.pid = t.pid and tt.uid = t.uid 
where tt.id < t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRCX1o6yFCcuhaNQ6uMBQL/0).
Results:

```
| id  | pid | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 5   | 3   | 2   |
| 6   | 2   | 5   |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delete` with `join`.  If you want to keep one row for all duplicate pairs:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select pid, uid, min(id) as min_id, count(*) as cnt
          from t
          group by pid, uid
         ) tt
         on tt.pid = t.pid and t.uid = tt.uid
    where t.id <> tt.min_id;
```

If you want to delete *all* duplicates, change the `where` to:

```
   where cnt >= 2
```

Comment: @SpeedRacer . . . That was also the first answer.

Comment: I Put both of them as answer but i think it tool only one

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
DELETE n1 FROM table n1 join
table n2 on n1.id > n2.id AND n1.PID = n2.PID and n1.UID=n2.UID
```